# Htaccess basic help needed

Tags: .htaccess

I'm trying to install friendica on my webhost (hourb, similar to 000webhost but with ssh).

I'm installing it to a directory/subdomain imoppen.domain.com (domain.com/imoppen)

But it says: Url rewrite in .htaccess is not working. Check your server configuration.
and i can't continue the installation.

I think it's something that has to do with directory's with the rewritebase part, but i don't know how to fix it.

It also gives a error in php, but that is not a very big deal for me;

```
 Warning: set_time_limit() has been disabled for security reasons in /home/username/public_html/imoppen/boot.php on line 290
```

My first .htaccess (domain.com) contains:

```
# DO NOT REMOVE THIS LINE AND THE LINES BELOW ERRORPAGEID:yLaNyW

ErrorDocument 404 /404.html

# DO NOT REMOVE THIS LINE AND THE LINES ABOVE yLaNyW:ERRORPAGEID

RewriteBase /
```

My second .htaccess (domain.com/installationdirectory) contains:

```
Options -Indexes
AddType application/x-java-archive .jar
AddType audio/ogg .oga

<FilesMatch "\.(out|log)$">
Deny from all
</FilesMatch>
SetEnv PHP_VER 5_3

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on
  # Protect repository directory from browsing
  RewriteRule "(^|/)\.git" - [F]

  # Rewrite current-style URLs of the form 'index.php?q=x'.
  # Also place auth information into REMOTE_USER for sites running
  # in CGI mode.

  # If you have troubles or use VirtualDocumentRoot
  # uncomment this and set it to the path where your friendica installation is
  # i.e.:
  # Friendica url: http://some.example.com
  # RewriteBase /
  # Friendica url: http://some.example.com/friendica
  # RewriteBase /imoppen/
  #
    RewriteBase /

  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [E=REMOTE_USER:%{HTTP:Authorization},L,QSA]

</IfModule>
```

As you can see I've tried to use the rewritebase part, which unfortunately did not work.
My overall php version is set to 5.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you are on hourb hosting (so am I) I solved it by going to settings -> htaccess -> Allow URL rewriting